# List all taxonomy longer than 28 characters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, taxonomy

I have an issue on my website caused by too much longer taxonomy in attributes. Someone can tell me if there is a way to see what are the longer taxonomy directly in DB?
I need to see all attribute taxonomy longer than 32 characters.

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12294

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is a way to know how are taxonomy longer than 28 characters with a query directly on db?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !empty( $_GET[ 'testmode' ] ) ) {
    $terms = get_terms();

    $maxlength_terms = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( strlen( $term->name ) > 28 ) {
            $maxlength_terms[] = $term;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $maxlength_terms as $key => $max_term ) {
        $update = wp_update_term( $max_term->term_id, $max_term->taxonomy, array(
            'name' => substr( $term->name, 0, 28 ),
        ) );
    }
}
```

Try adding this in your active theme functions.php and access your website URL like www.yoururl.com?testmode=1

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it as soon as possible. It should show me only taxonomy longer than 28 characters, is it?

Comment: @Fabrizio Yes it will be

Comment: You are great. It works well. I make you another question: there is a way to "cut" slug over 28 characters? Many of them in my website are taxonomy that refer to model of motorcycle. The final part is not important to identify the model, so if there is a way, I'd like to cut it automatically. I'll save many many hours of work. Thanks

Comment: Hi, with this update it will "cut" name automatically. But I think that problem could be also in slug. To do the same thing with slug I need to change term->name with term->slug, is it? I have this error in my website and I can't see all products page Warning: register_taxonomy was incorrectly called. Taxonomy names must be between 1 and 32 characters long

Comment: 'slug' => substr( $term->slug, 0, 28 ),

Comment: Hi, i've used your script but nothing change. It probably is a problem caused by attributes taxonomy. How can i "cut" attribute slug in table wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies ?